# How to make a calculated member in MDX for SSAS?

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, olap, olap-cube

I have a problem in my calculation and can't solve.

### Example:

Our company sells about 100 products, divided into categories and product ID. Product ID is the smallest granularity.
I need to show how this product list we sell in each city.

See the picture:

[image]

Overall, without showing the category it works well, however, when I show the product category it doesn't show how many products sold in that category, just repeats the full amount. And when I view the product ID, it returns the correct amount, which is equivalent to 1, follows the example pictures.

I used the following code, I will put generic way for better understanding.

```
COUNT(NONEMPTY([ProductDimension].[Category].[Product ID].Members,
               [Measures].[Valor Total]))
```

---

### UPDATE 1

I made some changes, and it's working, however when I put in excel, and I use a Subcategory slicer or filter, and I just select a subcategory, it shows the right count for the selected subcategory, however if I select 2 or more, it shows the count total of all categories, not just the two or more selected.

I am using this code MDX:

```
COUNT((NONEMPTY([ItensRadiografia].[Referência].[Referência],[Measures].[Valor Total]),
                [ItensRadiografia].[Família].CURRENTMEMBER))
```

I have little knowledge, but I'm studying a book called "MDX Step by Step", however I need this response faster than'll get to read this book.

---

### UPDATE 2

Follow the image:

[image]

The product dimension connects in the fact through `ItemSK`, which is the product code, the smallest granularity.

[image]

In the Dimension, `Familia` is a Category and `Referencia` is a ProductKey. The others are variations of how to write.

All hierarchies are composed Category and Product, except the last which is a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(all previous updates of answer were removed due to requirements discussion stage)

Add **Distinct Count** measure on `ItemSK` field, it will solve the problem.

Comment: Apologize for forgetting to translate, but that's it.

I've tried to do so, but it shows the total amount of factory products for all cities, regardless of sale or not.

Comment: I've updated an answer, Lucas. Please write here if it's not what you want.

Comment: Using the calculation `DISTINCTCOUT (nonempty (([group]. [Product_ID]))` and just putting the scope? Look at my update in question

Comment: Unfortunately, several members can't be used in this solution, since CurrentMember can work only with single members. I think, it's better to use another approach at all. Is 'Referencia' the lowest granularity level? How is it mapped?

Comment: Yes, is the smallest granularity. I have to thank you, is explaining to me some things I did not know.

Comment: Good, so the next question: how is 'Referencia' mapped? Is it a dimension with the key Referencia_ID (or smth like that) that is connected to cube with field Referencia_ID? Could you please attach here Dimension Usage tab of this dimension in cube?

Comment: Understood. Have you tried to add Distinct Count measure on ItemSK? You said "I've tried to do so, but it shows the total amount of factory products for all cities, regardless of sale or not.". Is it a Sales fact table? Or other items are present there?

Comment: Is a Sales Fact Table. I tried it now, tested, and I'm feeling a big idiot, is working perfectly. Thank you.

I would like to ask you some contact, skype, email ...? Could you tell me some?

Comment: Sure thing! skype: alex_peshik